# Learning to learn RegEx i need to find RegEx . ? ! ;

Tags: javascript, regex

Learning to learn RegEx i need to find RegEx for these symbols . ? ! ; ...

Thank you For Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***These are meta-characters which have special meaning in regex so you need to escape them.***

***Backspace (`\`) is used for escaping these meta-characters.***

like this `\.`, `\/`, `\?`

Comment: /\., \?, \!, \;/ like this ?

Comment: Well i don't know you want to match one or more at a time, how is pattern.
Well a better test string example will help better to understand and explain. Show me the string you trying to match.

Comment: no only if one of them in String

Comment: @AlbertJovinskyi `[\/.!;?]` like this.

Comment: what about three dots ?

Comment: @AlbertJovinskyi you can readup here more about regex https://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 1):

Use a backslash as escape character `\.`, `\?`, `\!`, `\;`
But you're only going to need a backslash, if the character you want to mask has a meaning in RegExp. E.g the caret character `^` has a meaning of

1. start of the string/line
2. negate a character class (only if used at the beginning of character class)

So you need to write `\^` and `[\^A-Z]`, but not `[A-Z\^]` (here `[A-Z^]` would be sufficent)

In your example, `!` and `;` don't need masking